# Hardcoded QMAKESPEC in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, installation

I installed Qt SDK (Qt framework + Qt Creator) but didn't like the layout of folders so I deleted it (without uninstalling), moved framework in one place and Qt Creator in another and installed Qt framework and Qt Creator separately placing each over the respective old one.

The problem is Qt Creator in *Projects/Build Settings/Build Steps* keeps showing the old path to the specification file:
*-spec c:/qt/2009.03/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++*

Setting *QMAKESPEC* environment variable either in the system or in *Projects/Build Environment* doesn't change anything.

How can I force Qt Creator to see and use new location of the specification file?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and am extremely interested in whether you found any solution.

Answer (score 4):

This does not fully solve the issue but if you add '-spec' (without quotes) in the additional arguments box in build steps -> qmake, then it removes the win32-g++ argument.

---

***NOTE:*** I have NOT been able to build the project after doing this (i changed it to win32-icc and win32-msvc2008 as i have both the intel c++ compiler and VS2008) but the build fails with the error ---- "*** MIssing Separator. Stop." in the makefile

Comment: IIRC, when I have had "Missing Separator. Stop" errors, the problem was related to DOS/Windows paths with "C:\xxx\yyy" in an environment expecting Unix style paths.  I believe adding "-unix" to the qmake line fixed this.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Qt Creator installed, but I suppose it may store this setting somewhere on filesystem, look in your %HOME% or %APPDATA% for directories associated with Qt Creator and search the files inside for this path.

Comment: Dear Paul, Sorry for writing here. As you have no E-mail in your profile, I decided to tell you something here. I intent to say THANK YOU SO MUCH. YOUR ANSWER WAS WHAT I WANT. But I feel sorry for other who do down vote or make fun of question as they did not understand correctly. THANK YOU SO MUCH. Now I can access to an object with its name. I will delete this comment after couple of minutes. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into Projects->Build Settings->General and clicking on the "Manage Qt Versions" and making sure that everything there is all correct?